# PHPMailer, from EC2 to SES AWS limits

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ses, moodle

I need a clarification on something.

I have installed Moodle on an 2 EC2 instances as cluster. Moodle is using PHPMailer.

In the settings of Moodle I have set the SMTP host as email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Since our Moodle is sending a LOT of emails, we have requested to upgrade SES so that the limit is raised but my question is: do I need to request a raise limit of sending emails of my EC2 instances as well?

Thank you
Kind regards
Christos

Comment: Are you using port 587 to connect to SES?  If not, which port are you using?

Comment: Moodle is using port 25 by default. So I believe port 25 is used.

Comment: Switch it to 587 and see what you observe.